# Vibrating screen on scroll using transform: scale

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-transforms

I would like a zoom out effect for my header, what loads zoomed in, and on scroll it zoom out.

What I do is to increase the size with transform: scale(1.4) and on scroll I calculate a percentage from the scrollTop and header height and I multiply it with 0.4. The problem is that on scroll the screen starts to vibrate, the scale isn't smooth. Do you have any idea what's wrong with my code or can you tell me what's the best practice to achieve this?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    function zoom_out() {
        var page_header_height = jQuery('#page-header-custom').outerHeight();
        var scroll_top = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
        var zoom_multiplier = 0.4;
        var multiplier = (zoom_multiplier*(1-((scroll_top-jQuery('#page-header-custom').offset().top)/page_header_height))) > 1 ? 1 : (zoom_multiplier*(1-((scroll_top-jQuery('#page-header-custom').offset().top)/page_header_height)));

        if(multiplier <= 1) {
            jQuery('#page-header-inner').stop(true, true).transition({ scale: 1/(1+multiplier), translate: '0, -50%'  });

            jQuery('#page-header-custom').stop(true, true).transition({
                scale: 1+multiplier
            });
        }
    }

    zoom_out();

    jQuery(window).on('scroll', function(){
        zoom_out();
    });
});
```

I created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8vb3kof9/1/) to see it in action.

Comment: Please check this; https://jsfiddle.net/8vb3kof9/3/

Comment: if you rewrite your code you can get some extra smoothness
few notes:
put `var header = jQuery('#page-header-custom');` and `var header_inner = jQuery('#page-header-inner');` outside of the `zoom_out` function. if possible remove that jquery selections inside `zoom_out` fn. Your `page_header_height` is always `800px`. Optimizing the frequently firing function gives you a smoothness. if this is not enough you can take a look at [Greensock](http://greensock.com/gsap) ;)

Comment: You may want to look at [`window.requestAnimationFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) to get it to smoothly transition and drop the `scroll` event handler.

Answer (score 1):

I've [updated your Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/javasluud/8vb3kof9/8/) with smooth scaling using [`window.requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame). The scale animation is vibrating because you're triggering a translation on each `scroll` event. Think about it like this:

1. user scrolls
2. `zoom_out()` gets triggered and tells an element to transition it's `transform` properties. Your element is now transitioning at a certain speed: "length" / transitiontime.
3. More `scroll` events have passed and are all triggering `zoom_out()`. The next transition will probably happen at a different speed, resulting in 'vibrating' animation.

First you can get rid of jQuery's `transition()` method. If you fire the function at 60fps or close to 60fps it will appear to animate smoothly to the human eye, without the need of transitioning or animating.

```
if(multiplier <= 1) {
        //jQuery('#page-header-inner').stop(true, true).transition({ scale: 1/(1+multiplier), translate: '0, -50%' });
        //jQuery('#page-header-custom').stop(true, true).transition({ scale: 1+multiplier });
        //becomes:

        jQuery('#page-header-inner').css({ scale: 1/(1+multiplier), translate: '0, -50%' });
        jQuery('#page-header-custom').css({ scale: 1+multiplier });           
    }
}
```

Getting the function triggered at ~60fps can be achieved in multiple ways:

[Throttle](https://remysharp.com/2010/07/21/throttling-function-calls) your scroll event to 60fps.

Or use [window.requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) like in the updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/javasluud/8vb3kof9/8/)

```
function zoom_out(){
  //calculation code & setting CSS

  window.requestAnimationFrame(zoom_out);
}

//trigger it once instead of the scroll event handler
window.requestAnimationFrame(zoom_out);
```